# Given all roots, how do I find the coefficients of a polynomial in time faster than O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm

Given all the roots of a polynomial, I have to figure out an algorithm that generates the coefficients faster than O(n^2). I'm having trouble approaching this problem. I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use the concept of a Fast Fourier Transform or Inverse Fourier Transform, but I don't know how to modify the input to not be the nth roots of unity. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1. What domain?  (R,C,...?)   2. what is wrong with direct polynomial writing for R domain for example:  `roots={ x0,x1,x2,x3,x4 } -> polynom(x) =(x-x0)*(x-x1)*(x-x2)*(x-x3)*(x-x4)` so you need just algebraicaly multiply it to get the coefficients ... 3. what is `N` ? the number of roots? in that case the multiplication is sadly O(N^2) ... so may be FFT polynomial multiplication ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an O(n * (log n)^2) solution:

1. The base case: for one root a, the answer is just x - a.
2. Let's assume that we have a list of more than one root. We can solve the problem recursively for the first and the second half of the list and then multiply the results using Fast Fourier Transform.

The time complexity is obtained from the equation T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + O(n log n), which is O(n * (log n)^2) according to the Master theorem.

Comment: I had thought of something like this, but I messed up the recurrence setup. If I had four roots, r1, r2, r3, r4, the algorithm basically multiplies the binomials of r1 and r2, and r3 and r4, and then the result of both correct?

Answer (score 2):

kraskevich basically nailed it.  Some details are missing, and it would be too long to fit into the comment field.  Here are the details.

Basically, you want to set up as a polynomial multiplication problem.  Your input would be p1,...pN where pj(x) = (x-rj).

Here's pseudo-code:

```html
function multiply2Poly(p1, p2)

   // here, use FFT, multiply and use IFFT back


function multiplyPoly(p[1],...p[N])
    if (N==1) return p[1]
    if (N==2) return multiply2Poly(p[1],p[2])
    else {
         return multiply2Poly(multiplyPoly(p[1],...p[N/2]),multiplyPoly(p[1+N/2],...,p[N])
    }


function getCoef(r[1],...r[N])

    return multiplyPoly((p[1]=x-r[1]),...(p[N]=x-r[N]));
```

And for the FFT part:

Observe that if two polynomials are:

```
p1 = a[0]+a[1] x + ...+a[n] x^n
p2 = b[0]+a[1] x + ...+a[n] x^n
```

Then p1 * p2 = c[0] + c[1] x + ...+c[n] x^n

where C = A [x] B where [x] = convolution.  A = (a[0],...,a[n]), B = (b[0],...,b[n]) and C = (c[0],...,c[n]).

Then use FFT and the convolution theorem to speed this up.

C = A [x] B = IFFT{ FFT{A} * FFT{B} } where * here is just multiplication.

runtime of IFFT = runtime of FFT = O(n log n).
multiplication run time is n, so the total run time is O(n log n).

The total run time of multiplyPoly is then:

T(N) = R(N/2) + T(N/2)*2

And R(N/2) = O(n log n) is the run time of multiply2Poly as described above.

so

T(N) = T(N/2) * 2 + O(n log n)

and now the Master theorem gives the O(n (log n)^2)