Is there a simple and efficient way to evaluate Elementary Symmetric Polynomials in Python?
I'm currently working on a project that involves evaluating Elementary Symmetric Polynomials (or "ESPs") using Python. So essentially I need to create a function that :

takes a non-empty list x (of numeric values) as an input
outputs a list containing all the corresponding ESP evaluations, where each ESP is in len(x) variables (also, by convention, we could say that the "0-th" ESP is always equal to 1)

For example, if my input list is x = [x1, x2, x3], then I want the function to output the list [1, x1 + x2 + x3, x1 * x2 + x1 * x3 + x2 * x3, x1 * x2 * x3].
I initially wrote a function that iterated over all the k-tuples of x (for all integers k in the range [1, len(x)]) using the "itertools.combinations" method, but it obviously didn't scale up well, as the time complexity of my function was exponential : it was in O(len(x) * 2^len(x)). So I was wondering if there was any algorithm that could do the same job, but in polynomial time (say, with a quadratic or a cubic time complexity).
I then stumbled upon Newton's identities (linking ESPs to power sums), and it does the job in a cubic time complexity (EDIT : actually it's in quadratic time complexity) ! For my purposes this time complexity is good enough, but is there a more efficient way of evaluating ESPs ? After some research, I didn't see any Stack Overflow posts with explicit code to solve my problem (although this Math Stack Exchange post does mention some algorithms). I also went through the following resources :

The pySymmPol package (and the corresponding article) : it looked promising, but in fact it doesn't support polynomial evaluation ...
This article, describing a fast algorithm to evaluate ESPs (with floating-point inputs) : unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the authors provide any code, and their algorithms seem very tedious to implement (also I think they said their code was written in C)

Additionally, here is the improved function that I implemented to solve my initial problem, using Newton's identities :
def evaluate_all_ESPs(x: list) -> list:
    """
    This function evaluates all the Elementary Symmetric Polynomials (or
    "ESPs") in `len(x)` variables on the given input list of numeric values,
    and returns the corresponding `len(x) + 1` evaluations in a list

    If we label these evaluated ESPs as `e[k]` (where `0 <= k <= len(x)`), we have :
        • `e[0] = 1` (by convention)
        • For all integers `1 <= k <= len(x)`, `e[k]` will be equal to the sum of all
          the products of k-tuples of `x` :
              - `e[1] = x[0] + x[1] + ... + x[-1]` (sum of all the elements of `x`)
              - `e[2] = x[0] * x[1] + x[0] * x[2] + ... + x[-2] * x[-1]` (sum of all
                the "double-products" of elements of `x`)
              - ...
              - `e[len(x)] = x[0] * x[1] * ... * x[-1]` (product of all the elements of `x`)

    Note : This function uses Newton's identities to make the computations *much*
           faster than if we had manually iterated over all the k-tuples of `x`
           (for each integer `k` in the range `[1, len(x)]`) ! Also, this algorithm's
           complexity is in `O(len(x)**2)`
    """
    # doing some quick input checks
    if not(isinstance(x, list)):
        raise TypeError(f"\n\nExpected a list, but got a '{type(x).__name__}' instead : '{x}'\n")
    if len(x) == 0:
        raise ValueError("\n\nThe input cannot be the empty list !\n")

    # initialization
    nb_elements = len(x)
    evaluations = [1] + [0] * nb_elements   # corresponds to the list labelled as `e` in the docstring
    powers_of_x = [1] * nb_elements         # list that'll contain all the `x[k]**i` values
    sums_of_powers_of_x = [0] * nb_elements # list that'll contain all the `sum(x[k]**i over k)` values

    for i in range(nb_elements):
        # updating `powers_of_x` and `sums_of_powers_of_x`
        powers_of_x = [x_k * previous_power_of_x_k for (x_k, previous_power_of_x_k) in zip(x, powers_of_x)]
        sums_of_powers_of_x[i] = sum(powers_of_x)

        # applying Newton's identity for the current evaluation
        # (SOURCE : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)
        current_evaluation = 0
        alternating_sign = 1
        for j in range(i, -1, -1):
            current_evaluation += alternating_sign * evaluations[j] * sums_of_powers_of_x[i - j]
            alternating_sign *= -1
        if isinstance(current_evaluation, int):
            current_evaluation //= i + 1
        else:
            current_evaluation /= i + 1

        # updating `evaluations`
        evaluations[i + 1] = current_evaluation

    return evaluations

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I haven't seen any explicit Python code on the internet that implements Newton's identities for the evaluation of ESPs. So hopefully this post will save some time for other people in my situation !

If this is a question, what's the actual question please? If it's a question which answers itself, the answer should be a separate entity that is an answer, rather than being embedded in the question. I think.

I don't know anything about ESPs, but my guess is that you can make use of sympy for this.

@MarkSetchell As mentioned in my post, I'm trying to figure out if there is a more efficient way of evaluating ESPs ! My current implementation is in O(len(x)^3), but I'm wondering if the time complexity could be reduced or not

@Barmar Thanks for the info ! Will look into it

@Barmar In the end NumPy was sufficient to solve my problem ! I didn't find any explicit ways of using sympy, but thanks anyway !

Surely you can do it just from the coefficients of the polynomial constructed from those roots?
e.g. x1=1, x2=2, x3=3
The polynomial is (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = x3-6x2+11x-6
The coefficients are the ESPs with alternating signs: 1, -(x1+x2+x3), +(x2.x3+x3.x1+x1.x2), -x1.x2.x3 etc.
Similarly for larger lists.
Code: (Credit @no comment for the alternating-sign correction)
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

def getESP( a ):
   c = np.array( Polynomial.fromroots(a).coef )
   esp = c[-1::-1]           # reverse array so that x^N is first
   esp[1::2] *= -1           # correct for alternating signs
   return esp

c = getESP( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
print( c )

Output:
[ 1.  6. 11.  6.]


Nice ! I didn't know NumPy had a polynomial module ... I tested your function, and, on my laptop, it"s slower for len(x) <= 70, and consistently much faster for len(x) > 70 ! This indicates that its time complexity is lower than O(len(x)^3) ! Thanks for the solution

How about esp[1::2] *= -1 instead of the loop?

@bghost Did you compare all solutions fairly? That is, did you test all with floats or all with arbitrary-size ints?

Thanks, @no comment. It's a good suggestion for a vectorized improvement. Overall, constructing a polynomial from roots should be O(N^2). (At least it would be if I did it from scratch myself. N factors, each multiplying into O(N) coefficients.) So I think the whole thing is O(N^2).

It might be faster. I tested with I think N=100000 and N=200000 and they both finished in seconds and the latter took only about twice as long.

I'll go with that, then! Code change made.

I misremembered. Tried it again now, with input [0.999] * N. Takes about 4 seconds for 100000 and about 12 seconds for 200000. So thrice as long, not twice. But still better than four times which you expect from quadratic. Attempt This Online!

Oh, sorry I was unclear. With "faster" I wasn't talking about my code suggestion (didn't measure that) but about your solution seeming faster than quadratic.

I'm pretty sure that your code suggestion would also improve things. With regards to the complexity your sample gave me just under three times as long. I'll see if I can find out how the numpy fromroots() method works, as I'm sure if I'd done it from scratch it would be O(N^2). Not sure if you could do a divide-and-conquer approach rather than multiplying one factor in at a time.

Ah right, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465398/given-all-roots-how-do-i-find-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-in-time-faster-t gives O(N * (log N)^2). Need to get my head round this Master Theorem.

@nocomment Yes I compared the solutions fairly ! But I guess the runtime ratios might vary a bit from one laptop to another (my laptop isn't very powerful tbh). Also, thanks for the code improvement you pointed out earlier

@bghost I'm still wondering how. With arbitrary-size ints or with floats? I didn't find a way to make Polynomial.fromroots not use floats. Did you find one? And I think with floats, Raymond's solution is quadratic, but you said it seems cubic, so it seems you didn't test it with floats?

The polynomial_from_roots() function in the itertools recipes or the more-itertools package will do this.
Given x = [2, 3, 5], compute this:
>>> polynomial_from_roots([-2, -3, -5])
[1, 10, 31, 30]

Here is the underlying source code:
from itertools import islice, chain, repeat
import collections
import functools
import math
import operator

def sliding_window(iterable, n):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    window = collections.deque(islice(iterator, n - 1), maxlen=n)
    for x in iterator:
        window.append(x)
        yield tuple(window)

def convolve(signal, kernel):
    kernel = tuple(kernel)[::-1]
    n = len(kernel)
    padded_signal = chain(repeat(0, n-1), signal, repeat(0, n-1))
    windowed_signal = sliding_window(padded_signal, n)
    return list(map(math.sumprod, repeat(kernel), windowed_signal))

def polynomial_from_roots(roots):
    factors = zip(repeat(1), map(operator.neg, roots))
    return list(functools.reduce(convolve, factors, [1]))


Thanks for the answer ! I tested it, and unfortunately it seems to also be in O(len(x)^3) (as it's consistently 2x slower than my function, as I increase len(x)). It's an interesting solution though !

@bghost The algorithm is considered quadratic because the number of multiplies is n**2 + 3*n where n is the number of roots.  For float inputs, you will see consistent quadratic timings.  But for integer inputs, timings will gradually shift from quadratic to almost cubic for larger values of n.  This is because arbitrary precision arithmetic gets slower when values get larger than the native word size. For example, x * x takes 3x longer for x=2**2000 than for x=2**1000.

Sorry for the late reply. I was wrong about the complexity of my algorithm ! It's also in quadratic time complexity (and not cubic like I initially thought). I edited the question/code with the corresponding changes. Thanks for looking into this, though.
